# What is a "unique event" in Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events

I don´t really catch the whole sense of an unique event. Can anybody explain it with a claryfing example?

Under my point of view, it is an event that is only done once into a session. For example: a user click in a play button video twice, and in a confirmation button only one. So the confirmation button clickment is an event unique, but the button video is not, because it was clicked twice. Am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

When Google Analytics gives you a count of unique events, it is telling you how many sessions had one or more of that event.

For example, you have 3 users that may or may not have clicked the play button some number of times:

- Alice: 3 clicks
- Bob: 1 click
- Charlie: 0 clicks

There would be 4 total events but only 2 unique events, one from Alice, and one from Bob.  The second and third clicks from Alice would count towards "total events", but not towards "unique events" because Alice had already completed that event once in that session.

Google documents this in [Unique Events and Unique Dimension Combinations - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7084499?hl=en) and explains it like:

> Analytics increments the Unique Events metric by 1 the first time during a session that it receives an event with a unique combination of Category/Action/Label, and ignores subsequent events in the session that have the same combination of Category/Action/Label.

Comment: Let's see if I understood. Alice clicked 3 times: 2 times the play button and other the download pdf button. there would be 2 unique events?: one for the play button and other for the download button...

Comment: Correct, as long as you are sending different category, action, or label information for clicking on those two different buttons.